# Allow HTTP request from mobile browsers exclusively

Tags: c#, android, iphone, asp.net-mvc-3

Is it possible to allow a user to access a page that creates random numbers only for mobile browsers?

Is there an easy way to do this?

Should I check the browser and agent against the mobile ones?

Essentially, I don't want users to hit a URL with a web browser from their PCs.

Comment: Most desktop browsers allow users to change user-agent field. Firefox even comes with an addon that mimic mobile browser user-agent. In short, you cannot prevent the most determined users to access your site from desktop browser, or even a custom application that disguise as mobile browser.

Comment: However, if you're doing this for usability concerns (and **not** security), then checking the user agent is the common way to detect mobile browsers.

Comment: http://51degrees.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can by detecting either by checking the value returned from servevaraible  HTTP_USER_AGENT  or HttpContext.Request.Browser.IsMobileDevice and allow httprequest on your mobile page

Example on http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/34422/Detecting-a-mobile-browser-in-ASP-NET